# Java If/Else Multiple Conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am using an If/Else statement in Java with multiple conditions. Originally, I had 8 nested if statements, but combined them into one if with multiple && connectors. All conditions must be passed in order for the listed results to be shown. If any one condition is failed, the else statement must pass. I think I have structured my block correctly, but during testing the required results are not working properly. For example, I have changed ageCustInt so that it should fail and show "Not Compatible". This worked perfectly, then I changed ageCustInt back to an age that should pass, but I am still getting "Not Compatible". I have checked each of the other conditions and they all pass. Is my code incorrectly structured? I simply can not find why I am not getting correct results.

```
if (ageCustInt >= ageMinComp1Int && ageCustInt <= ageMaxComp1Int &&
            adtV1MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int && adtV2MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int && adtV3MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int &&
            adtV1MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int && adtV2MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int && adtV3MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int &&
            totalViolationsCustInt >= totalViolationsMinComp1Int && totalViolationsCustInt <= totalViolationsMaxComp1Int &&
            totalAdtDriversCustInt >= adtDriversMinComp1Int && totalAdtDriversCustInt <= adtDriversMaxComp1Int &&
            bodilyInjuryCust.equals(bodilyInjuryComp1) &&
            propDamageCust.equals(propDamageComp1) &&
            unUiBodilyCust.equals(unUiBodilyComp1))
                    {
                    btnComp1.setVisible(true);
                    lblPriceComp1.setText("$ " + price1String);
                    lblPriceComp1.setVisible(true);
                    }               
        else
        {
            lblPriceComp1.setText("Not Competitive");
        }
```

Comment: This will be next to impossible to debug and suggests that you should consider a radical re-design. Can you tell us what you think you need all of this? It also looks like you're mixing model with view code, and one refectoring that you should strongly consider is separating them -- creating a model that reflects the underlying state of the system, that is as view agnostic as possible, that should work just as well in a Swing GUI as in a console program or an Android program.

Comment: Does this really look like code that you want to maintain?

Comment: Not enough info provided to debug. Moreover, why are you using such code? Won't it be easy to redefine it to much simpler and easier code?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to make this code simpler and easier. I need some user entered data to either pass all of these conditions, or fail if any condition is not met. What more information could I provide to help make the debugging easier?

Comment: I hope you understand that "compatible" and "competitive" are words with completely different meanings?  Anyway, I don't see anything wrong with your code, so if it's giving you the wrong result, either one of the pieces of data isn't what you think it is, or the problem is with an `equals` method.  Since we can't see any of those, I don't think there's anything we can do to help, except to help you simplify the code.  But we can't help you spot the problem.

Comment: Here's one obvious thing: any time you have multiple variables with "1", "2", "3" in the name (or more), consider using an array.  You can write a method that uses a loop to check whether every element of an array falls within a range.

Comment: @ ajb Thank you! I went through each of the variables again and found and extra zero where is should not have been. Tricky guy! The code is working just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

One way to flatten it is by introducing a method with short-circuiting return statements

```
boolean check(args)
{
    if(expr1) 
        return false;
    if(expr2) 
        return false;
    ...
    return true;
}
```

We can also do it with a local block

```
boolean b=false;
check:
{
    if(expr1)
        break check;
    if(expr2)
        break check;
    ...
    b = true;
}

if(b) 
    ...
else
    ...
```

With lambda expression

```
Supplier<Boolean> check = ()->
{
    if(expr1) 
        return false;
    if(expr2) 
        return false;
    ...
    return true;
}

if(check.get()) ...
```